# Numbering figures in LaTeX with decimal points

Tags: latex, figure, overleaf

I want to number a set of `{figures}` in LaTeX as follows:

```
\section{introduction}

\begin{figure}[H]

    \centering

    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textheight]{nameof the figure}

    \caption{specification for the figure}

    \label{refertofigure1}

\end{figure}
```

This code renders as ***Figure 1: specification for the figure***,
and I want it display:

- The initial figure: ***Figure 1.1: specification for the figure***
- If I add another figure: ***Figure 1.2: specification for the figure***
- If I add another section: ***Figure 2.1: specification for the figure***

How can I express this in LaTeX?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] including a class and the necessary packages